# Calculus: given marginal cost function, find production cost function

Tags: calculus

The marginal cost for printing a paperback book at a small publishing company is
$c(p) = 0.012$ dollars per page where $p$ is the number of pages in the book.
A $650$ page book has a \$19.02 production cost. Find the production cost function $C(p)$.

I found $C(p)=0.006p^2-2515.98$ but the homework says its wrong and I'm not sure why.

Comment: How did you get to that cost function? We can't help you with what went wrong without knowing how you got there

Answer (score 0):

Given the information. The production cost function $P(x)$ where $x$ is the number of pages should be $$P(x)=0.012x+11.22$$
We know the cost of a book and cost of to print the pages in the book. Subtract cost to print the pages which changes with number of pages in the book and find the additional cost which is 11.22$.